# What are the values for, when using createTemplate in a contentByte class for iText?

Tags: pdf, itext

I am using iText and am very new to it.  There have been several situations where I think I could have figured out the problem with my code if I knew what I was doing - I use examples without knowing the workings behind the code, and even as I look at the source I can't figure out what the programmer was thinking.

What are the values for, when using createTemple in a contentByte class for iText?

for example:

```
total = cb.createTemplate(100,100);
```

where total is of type contentByte.

Answer (score 0):

It´is float width and float height of the template.
You might benefit from reading this.

http://api.itextpdf.com/itext/com/itextpdf/text/pdf/class-use/PdfTemplate.html